# C# string parsing problem

Tags: c#

I have a file thats exported with a ton of lines.  I want to be able to parse the file into a neat order that I can easily use.

I have a sample string here:

```
<a href="http://www.foxnews.com/us/2010/07/28/cemetery-allows-father-war-veteran-fly-flag-grave/?test=latestnews">deal reached on cemetery flags</a>
| <a href="#" onclick="foxgrabplayer('4295654','','grave insult to grieving family');return false;"><img src="/i/redes/icon-video.gif"></a><br>
- <a href="http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2010/07/27/obama-missing-historic-boy-scout-jamboree-fundraisers-view-taping/">obama skips out on scouts for 'the view'</a><br>
- <strong class="em">you decide: </strong><a href="http://www.foxnews.com/opinion/2010/07/27/decide-right-obama-miss-boy-scout-jamboree/">right call?</a></li>"
```

All of that is 1 line. I'd want it to output like the following:

```
http://www.foxnews.com/us/2010/07/28/cemetery-allows-father-war-veteran-fly-flag-grave|Deal reached on cemetery flags  
http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2010/07/27/obama-missing-historic-boy-scout-jamboree-fundraisers-view-taping|obama skips out on scouts for 'the view
```

sort of www|description for every href in the line.  Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Is the example string supposed to be valid HTML?

Comment: Yes, i had to chop it up because i did not know how to get it to display full string on SOF

Comment: At the end of the day I am just trying to pull the hyperlink and description of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Html Agility Pack. The first example deals with hrefs: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home.

Answer (score 1):

I really hate to say this but.  Use regular expressions. `href="(.*?)"` should get you all the hrefs.  May need a bit of tweaking to eliminate things you don't want.  Here is a decentish article on implementation http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/csharp-regular-expressions.html